# What is the best way to mock os.system for unit test (PyTest)

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, pytest

I have a Python script that does multiple `os.system` calls. Asserting against the series of them as a list of strings will be easy (and relatively elegant).

What isn't so easy is intercepting (and blocking) the actual calls. In the script in question, I could abstract os.system in the SUT (*) like so:

```
os_system = None

def main():
    return do_the_thing(os.system)

def do_the_thing(os_sys):
    global os_system
    os_system = os_sys

    # all other function should use os_system instead of os.system
```

My test invokes `my_script.do_the_thing()` instead of `my_script.main()` of course (leaving a tiny amount of untested code).

**Alternate option:** I could leave the SUT untouched and replace `os.system` globally in the test method before invoking `main()` in the SUT.

That leaves me with new problems in that that's a global and lasting change. Fine, so I'd use a `try/finally` in the same test method, and replace the original before leaving the test method.  That'd work whether the test method passes or fails.

Is there a safe and **elegant** setup/teardown centric way of doing this for PyTest, though?

Additional complications: I want to do the same for stdout and stderr.  Yes, it really is a `main()` script that I am testing.

- SUT == System Under Test

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Python 3 (>= 3.3) standard library has a [great tutorial about Mock](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#module-unittest.mock) in the official documentation. For Python 2, you  can use the backported library: [Mock](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mock) on PyPi.

Here is a sample usage. Say you want to mock the call to `os.system` in this function:

```
import os


def my_function(src_dir):
    os.system('ls ' + src_dir)
```

To do that, you can use the `unittest.mock.patch` decorator, like this:

```
import unittest.mock


@unittest.mock.patch('os.system')
def test_my_function(os_system):
    # type: (unittest.mock.Mock) -> None
    my_function("/path/to/dir")
    os_system.assert_called_once_with('ls /path/to/dir')
```

This test function will patch the `os.system` call during its execution. `os.system` is restored at the end.

Then, there are several "assert" method to check the calls, the parameters, and the results. You can also check that an exception is raised in certain circonstances.

Comment: Great. For PyTest and Python2 it is just @mock.patch('os.system') and I can confirm works quite well.

Comment: This does not work at all for me. Commands are still executed using the real os.system.

Answer (score 3):

Just want to add an important detail.

If your code uses `import system` for example like this:

*myls.py*:

```
import os


def do_ls():
    os.system('ls')
```

Then the patch in your test should look like this:

*test_myls.py*:

```
from unittest.mock import patch


@patch('os.system')
def test_do_ls(mock_system):
    do_ls()
    mock_system.assert_called()
```

However, if the code uses `from os import system`, e.g. like this:

*myls.py*:

```
from os import system


def do_ls():
    system('ls')
```

Then the patch in your test should look like this:

*test_myls.py*:

```
from unittest.mock import patch


@patch('myls.system')
def test_do_ls(mock_system):
    do_ls()
    mock_system.assert_called()
```

This eluded me for a bit because I had forgotten to read the section on [where to patch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#id6) as I originally intended. If patching does not seem to work, this is one of the points to look at.